# How can I remove scrollbar of an Internet Explorer ActiveX

Tags: internet-explorer, scrollbar, activex

I'm embedding an IE com into my program. Actually a QAxWidget.
I want to hide the scrollbars no matter how large the content is. But I have no idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in control of the content of html pages that it will be visiting, you can use `<body scroll="no">` or `overflow: hidden;` in the css of the element that is scrolling.